# .net HttpClient POST works only with Fiddler

Tags: c#, .net, post, httpclient, fiddler

This is an old question, but I still can't find a solution.

The old project (.net 4.6.1) uses HttpClient to get json from python-flask. Now we need to POST json to this endpoint via HttpClient. But it got stuck on SendAsync. I tried endless combinations with other methods as well. But POST works fine when Fiddler is running on the computer. I read that Fiddler made another request to overcome the proxy - but I don't have any proxy. Also the same code works perfectly in .core - unfortunately I have to solve this with. net framework. Furthermore, I read somewhere that the problem is because .net sends the header separately as the body. But I can't solve it with the existing code. I don't know if it's a bug in WebApi or how to solve it?
Also the endpoint works fine when I POST with Postman or php or javascript...

Here is the code

```
static HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler
{
    Proxy = null
});

public async Task<ActionResult> GetJson()
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://endpoint/");
    var content = new StringContent("{\r\n    \"date_from\": 20230208,\r\n    \"date_to\": 20230307\r\n }", null, "application/json");

    _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders
      .Accept
      .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    request.Content = content;
    var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    return Content(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
}
```

I tried other methods sync and async, closing streams, using 'using', settings in web.config, updating WebApi dll, also tried RestApi and Furl, but apparently they all use the same basic .net method.

Comment: try usine `PostAsync` insead of `SendAsync`

Comment: I'm just curious, how come you tagged Python for this question?

Comment: `ReadAsStringAsync().Result` is bad, especially if you method is marked `async`, just await it - `return Content(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false));`

Comment: Also can you please make more evident how exactly the method does not work?

Comment: _"But it got stuck on SendAsync"_ - If it is exactly stuck - try adding configure await - `await _httpClient.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);`.

Comment: Also can you please show how `GetJson` is called, I have a theory about what is actually wrong)

Comment: If you need to use Net use version 4.7.2 or later.  Net 4.7.2 fixed a lot of issues with encryption and server may be switching from HTTP to HTTPS and 4.6.1 does not handle all the encryption modes for TLS.  Starting with 4.7.2 TLS is performed in OS instead of Net.  Comparing Net 4.6.1 and Fiddler is like comparing apples and oranges.  Fiddler is too different to explain why your code doesn't work.

Comment: Are you getting HTTP STATUS 0 code or empty? Is your endpoint SSL?

Comment: #user56700 - Because posting to other services works - as I said I need help for this particular issue. Python is the endpoint. And I can do post to this server with php, javascript (all methods, http, fetch, angular $http) so drives me crazy why nor work with .net. Simple and obvious task...

Comment: #jdweng - believe me, I've tried every variation - no luck. Core works great, but it's not a solution for me. Pondering how exactly it doesn't work. I set a breakpoint on SendAsync and the program stops there until the system times out. I also tried other methods that explicitly close everything but always hungs at GetResponse or whatever.